# ExtJS 6 with liferay 6.2

Tags: extjs, liferay

I have created an extjs-6 application using sencha cmd, you can find details [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/tutorials/login_app.html). Now I want to integrate extjs-6 into liferay 6.2. How I can integrate both liferay6.2 and extjs-6?

**Notes:**

One way I was able to achieve by creating war out of extjs-6 application and put war file in liferay deploy folder, but it was creating portlet with Iframe and I don't want Iframe in portlet.

Comment: How is the IFrame comming onto the page. Is it something generated by the JS framework?

Comment: Its generated by liferay deploy mechanism internally somehow.

Comment: Liferay does not generate IFrames it must have been done by the ExtJS framework or by you. I would assume that this should work similar to any modern JS frameworks. The approach is either to include the framework JS into the theme and have it shared for all the portlets. Alternatively, you can put it also in the portlet and define it in the liferay-portlet.xml have you seen this https://web.liferay.com/web/vitor.silva/blog/-/blogs/using-extjs-with-liferay